# How to filter by date in column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to filter `my_df` by the date in column header. I tried this and it did not work:

```
my_dict = {'Cat': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'Fri,01/01/21': {0: 181.0, 1: 359.0, 2: 162.0}, 'Sat,01/02/21': {0: 519.0, 1: 379.0, 2: 419.0}}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
my_df.columns = my_df.columns[:1].tolist() + pd.to_datetime(my_df.columns[1:]).tolist()
test = my_df.loc[:, my_df.columns <= datetime(2021, 1, 1)]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deal is

```
my_df.columns = my_df.columns[:1].tolist() + pd.to_datetime(my_df.columns[1:]).tolist()
```

This statement is casting the column header as a str.  Use the following to set index the 'Cat' column first then pd.to_datetime, to keep the date columns as datetime dtype.

And, also  my_df.columns

```
my_dict = {'Cat': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'Fri,01/01/21': {0: 181.0, 1: 359.0, 2: 162.0}, 'Sat,01/02/21': {0: 519.0, 1: 379.0, 2: 419.0}}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
my_df = my_df.set_index('Cat')
my_df.columns = pd.to_datetime(my_df.columns)
test = my_df.loc[:, my_df.columns <= datetime(2021, 1, 1)]
```

Output:

```
     2021-01-01
Cat            
A         181.0
B         359.0
C         162.0
```

Comment: I tried your same code and got the following error:
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: @StevenGonzález Try `from datetime import datetime`